# Altium Double Counting Unit Quantities in BOM?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium

I've got a schematic that has been through several revisions, and I noticed when generating my BOM that the most recent two revisions are now generating an error in Reports > Bill of Materials tool.  For some reason some components are being double counted.  Like a resistor that is only used once, is showing as a quantity of 2 in the generated BOM?

Has anyone ever run into this with Altium? The schematic two revisions ago, correctly counts the quantities but I evidently did something that upset Altium...

Comment: What are the part numbers in the BOM doing?

Comment: Does the BOM list 2 separate designators for that resistor?

Comment: Okay, so here is a clue... when I remove the schematic from the project, and open it as as free document, the BOM report is correct...  The part has only one designator, and the part number is unique.  I think the problem is that I have two .SchDocs open in the project (each revision of the schematic) so it is double counting each designator (as the schematics share the designators).  I would have assumed the BOM tool treats each .SchDoc as a seperate entity -- guess not.  I just saved myself from ordering an extra 500,000 passive components...

Comment: You should keep different schematic revisions in their own respective projects.

Comment: @DerStrom8 -- what I really should do is just use SVN for version control.  I use git for software, but am still doing ghetto manual version control for Altium. I just upgraded to using outjobs instead of manually clicking around.

Comment: That works too, it will ensure you have only the most recent revision in your project

Answer (score 2):

A second menu is provided from which you can specify the data source  that is to be used when the BOM report is generated.

Only pick the applicable data source.

Comment: Excellent, I will check that.  I just kind of speed through that BOM report tool.  Thank you.